# io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for DocumentSnapshot(#1).toObject(...)

Tags: kotlin, mocking, mockk

I'm using `.toObject(...)` when calling Firestore methods:

```kotlin
firestore.collection(collectionPath)
            .document(documentId).get().await()
            .toObject(MyClass::class.java)
```

and I'm wondering how to mock this call using MockK in Kotlin Android Studio.

The mock is:

```kotlin
val mockFirestore: FirebaseFirestore = mockk {
            coEvery {
                collection(path)
                    .document(documentId)
                    .get()
            } returns mockTask<DocumentSnapshot>(documentSnapshot)
        }
```

trying `.to` to see what completions pop up results in `.toString()`, `.toStr()` and `.toArray()`.

The error is:

```
io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for DocumentSnapshot(#1).toObject(class ...) among the configured answers: (DocumentSnapshot(#1).getId())
```

how can I mock the call to `.toObject(class)`?

Comment: You seem to be trying to mock a non-existent `Firestore.toObject()` but the error message says you need to mock `DocumentSnapshot.toObject()`. Look at your method `mockTask` which returns the mock `DocumentSnapshot`.

Comment: inside the mockk definition for DocumentSnapshot, you can add a coEvery for the toObject() ... try to return the mocked document snapshot in a mockked function for the firebasefirestore.

Comment: The fact that you are trying to mock Firestore means that there is something seriously wrong with your architecture. Firestore is a vendor-specific implementation of a real-time database and should be abstracted away from your business logic. After that, you don't need to test your Firestore implementation because, well Google has already tested it for you. Test what happens when your app interacts with any implementation of the realtime-database abstraction you end up creating.